# Sprintboot uploading image - Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]`

Tags: java, spring-boot, image

Im using Springboot and JPA.

I'm trying to insert an image as part of an entity by using `@LOB` and `byte[]` I remember seeing on a guide. Though I am uncertain of if / what other fields are requirements for image storage as I have not worked with them before.

here is the error thrown:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String "http://localhost:3000/55c945ee-6c2b-4ac8-a09f-4535cda25f2a": Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String "http://localhost:3000/55c945ee-6c2b-4ac8-a09f-4535cda25f2a": Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 154] (through reference chain: com.bolton.demospringboot0903.Models.Item["image"])]
```

here is the class:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public Double price;
    public LocalDate releaseDate;
    public int score;
    public Integer amount;
    public Integer stockCount;

    @Lob
    @Column(length = Integer.MAX_VALUE, nullable = true)
    public byte[] image;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "Item_category",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")})
    public Category category;
```

here is the object I am passing:
(I cant paste direct object because it wont copy image json it from chrome console)
[image]

Comment: what exception is thrown, can you share complete stacktrace?

Comment: @swapyonubuntu i managed to actually debug now, post is updated with error

Comment: it seems error you are getting at controller level itself where spring cannot read given input body and deserialize it to java object itself. So writing to database which happens later is out of question, i think first you need to fix this